# Get pointer to a previously opened file stream

Tags: windows, file, pointers, memory-management, c89

If we open some arbitrary file using `fopen()` we get a pointer to it and it seems on windows, it will be stored in varying address (for example `1fb8e50`)

---

So can I declare a second pointer to it, from another instance like that:

```
volatile FILE* fp = (volatile FILE*)0x1fb8e50;
```

And use them both. Is that dangerous or just possible for that matter?

Comment: There are no reasonable circumstances in which it would make sense to hard-code a `FILE` pointer into your source code.  What are you actually trying to do?

Comment: @HarryJohnston I am trying to satisfy my curiosity.

Comment: The pointer points to a memory block that `fopen` created, which is used to store information about the file stream.  If you haven't called `fopen`, the memory block doesn't exist, so you can't use it.  Generally speaking, you will get a different pointer each time you run the program.